# onclick listener in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I used two image button for Next and Back and i used onclick event for those button i want to which image button fire on onclick and run particular function for next or back in onclick event how will i get which image button fire or onclick event at runtime

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use anonymous inner classes to write an onClick function for each button.

```
Button button1 = getMyButton();
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // button 1 was clicked!
   }
  });
Button button2 = getMyButton();
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      // button 2 was clicked!
   }
  });
```

As Konstantin mentioned, you can also use the passed in View and switch on the id.  However, I find that a bit messier if you end up with lots of clickable things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the preferred method unless you have a lot of buttons

Answer (score 12):

Use View.getId() to distinguish between different views that fire onClick events.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.download:
    //code..
    break;
    case R.id.play:
    //code..
    break;
    case R.id.pause:
        //code..
    break;
    default:
        //code..
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i am using following concept 
 imgvw_back.setOnClickListener(this)
imgvw.setOnClickListener(this);
static int i=10;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 switch(v.getId())
 {
 case R.id.back:
             Log.v("back",""+i--);
             break;
             
 case R.id.forward:
        Log.v("next",""+i++);
        break;          
             
 }
 
}

but did not work,I don't know,why didnot run?mostly display next word in log

Comment: Have you tried to setup a breakpoint at the onClick method? Does it run at all?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simple by declaring a unique ID to both the `ImageButton` in **XML** as follows

```
<ImageButton 
     android:id="@+id/backButton"
     .../>
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/nextButton"
     .../>
```

Then in **JAVA** if you use

> Binding

which is by using ViewModel for your page then you can use the following code in `onCreate()` method and you must place your code inbetween `View root = binding.getRoot();` and `return root;`

```
View root = binding.getRoot();

ImageButton backBtn = binding.backButton;
ImageButton nextBtn = binding.nextButton;

//Now Comes the OnClickEvent using Lambda a easiest way

backBtn.setOnClickListener(a -> 
{
    //Your Handler Code for Back Button
});

nextBtn.setOnClickListener(b -> 
{
    //Your Handler Code for Next Button
});

return root;
```

Then for

> Normal

```
ImageButton backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backButton);
ImageButton nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);

//onClickListeners
backBtn.setOnClickListener(a -> 
{
    //Your Handler Code for Back Button
});    
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(b -> 
{
    //Your Handler Code for Next Button
});
```

This Lambda Expression can be done in two ways which are by

> Method 1

```
view.setOnCLickListener(method1 -> 
{
    //Your Handler Code
});
```

> Method 2

If you have already defined a function and you are going set this method then

```
view.setOnClickListener(method2 -> functionName(); );
```

Answer (score 0):

For set onClickListener to a text: Go to `activity_main.xml` and add:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="My Github"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

In `MainActivity.java` file add:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
AppCompatTextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView.setOnClickListener(view-> startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://github.com/fekri86114"))));
           
}
}
```