# make a list clickable

Tags: android, list

I have the below code:

```
   ArrayList NumList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra ("number");

   ArrayList MailList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra ("email");

    // This array list will be updated each time.

    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    mAdapter.addItem(Name);

    if (!NumList.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("Phone");
        mAdapter.addAll(NumList);
    }

    if (!MailList.isEmpty()) {
        mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("Email");
        mAdapter.addAll(MailList);
    }

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I want to be able to click on the list of numbers and call the selected number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are using a ListActivity or ListFragment, so implement your calling logic in onListItemClick or place an onClickListener on each of the views when you create them in your custom adapter like so:

```
view.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
  public boolean onClick( View view) {
    //do your stuff here
  }
});
```

The logic for making a call looks like this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

**Edit:**

And remember add this CALL_PHONE permission to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: I am using ListActivity but I can't seem to implement the listener, where exactly does it need to go?

Comment: onListItemClick is a protected method in ListActivity that you simply override. Method signature looks like: protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id). 
setOnClickListener is used on the view that you return from getView() in MyCustomAdapter

Comment: sorry I must be really dense, but what goes in the brackets of  convertView.setOnClickListener();

Comment: new OnClickListener(){
    public boolean onClick(View v){
        //your magic code
    }
}

Comment: i'm getting the error: Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener

Comment: See this question for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505841/onclick-listener-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This post will probably help you: [How to handle ListView click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto)

You have to instantiate an OnClickListener and register it with your ListView. Use setOnItemClickListener of the ListView class for this.