# Click again on button android

Tags: android, flash, button

I want create a flashlight app on android, i have put one button. When we click on it, the flash of smartphone go on. But when i click again on the button, the flash didn't go off.

I have use this code on github : https://github.com/sanbeg/flashlight/blob/master/src/io/github/sanbeg/flashlight/FlashLightActivity.java.

I have try to make

```
if (the_button.isChecked()) {
            flash.on();
            the_button.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        }
        else {
            flash.off();
            the_button.setKeepScreenOn(false);
        }
```

XML File :

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/flashlightButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: could you please post the xml file too...

Comment: you need to put and OnClickListener on this ------> the_button   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505841/onclick-listener-in-android

Comment: I would rather use a flag that changes its value (e.g. boolean) when the listener is triggered instead of what you are trying to do.