# Custom button form (House/Tree etc.)

Tags: android

I'm a bit new to Android, therefore question may sound ridiculous, but:

Is there any way to make a button in form of smthg? There ate tons of apps, where you press on a tree or some house and some action starts. How is that made?
Not action, but form. Or there is no way to make button NOT rectangular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create custom button in Android using XML Styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles)

Comment: Button is View like an ImageView or TextView, you might be talking about onClick Listeners see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505841/onclick-listener-in-android

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that your question is voted for closed by 2 persons so far, Due to the quality of post. Please post questions here once you tried and failed (Only after doing enough research on the same question). Also post the code, stacktrace or images of the problem that you are tackling to resolve.

Comment: Buttons are Views which are always rectangular but doesn't need to look like they are rectangular. Alternatively look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about imagebutton.[Image button documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

For example creating a button with tree background.Example:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/tree.png"></ImageButton>
```

Comment: Well, button will appear rectangular. But what if i want to make an cloud, for example?

Comment: Assign a shape to it.Create a shape drawable and assign the button background as that shape.
[example](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/07/19/android-shapes/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Considering your trees and house as an image.

```
    ImageView im;
    im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_of_tree);
    im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //perform some action
        }
    });
```

Comment: But can i do it NOT rectangular? i mean, button actually in form of tree.

Comment: Try this, I think rectangle will not appear in background.

Comment: Yeah, but when i'll press not on a tree, but somewhere near, still in rectangle area, it will do some action, which i don't want. That's why i asked how to make button JUST in form of smthg.

Comment: Okay, as mentioned above go to this link:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507351/how-to-create-custom-button-in-android-using-xml-styles

and give shape to to your background.

Answer (score 0):

Off-course When you get inflated your layout and your view(can be any view) is available by id. your button can be an ImageView, ImageButton etc. just find the id for your view and set whatever event you want to listen by this view.